# How do larger github projects combine files

Tags: git, jquery-ui

I see that large projects like the jQuery UI will be comprised of many small files like those in the [UI folder](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui). I was wondering how those files become combined to be the thing I download from the [website](http://jqueryui.com/download), or is that process unrelated?

Basically I'm looking to break up a large JS project into pieces and wondering if there's some automated way of stitching it back together for users to download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They use an ant script to build it:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/build/build.xml

Specifically:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/build/build.xml#L87 (concatenate target)

This is the code they use to concatenate all files into one:

```
<concat destfile="${dist.dir}/ui/${concatenated}.js">
  <filelist dir="${src.dir}/" files="${core.files}" />
  <fileset dir="${src.dir}/" includes="jquery.ui.*.js, jquery.effects.*.js" excludes="${core.files}" />
</concat>
```

Comment: Yes, I can see that directory.

Comment: The ant script can be called using the 'ant' command, which is a build system. If you run ant from that directory it runs the targets required to build the jquery-ui files, including the concatenate target to concatenate all files together.